# Not able to run python code in sublime text 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext, traceback

Whenever I tried to run my python code in sublime text 3 it shows the error of long paragraph like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\py_compile.py", line 218, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\py_compile.py", line 209, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\py_compile.py", line 157, in compile
    os.makedirs(dirname)
  File "C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\os.py", line 221, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Abhishek Kumar\\Documents\\html\\__pycache__'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -m py_compile "C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\Documents\html\hello.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\Documents\html]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Python27;C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32;C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts;C:\Users\Abhishek Kumar\AppData\Local\Sublime Text 3\Cache;C:\;]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are in the same working directory and that __pycache__ is in the same directory as well?

Comment: Regardless of other issues you might be having, you're using the build system variant that only compiles your code and doesn't run it (the command includes `-m py_compile`) so even if this error didn't occur, your program still wouldn't run. You need to use `Tools > Build With...` and pick the Python build that doesn't say `Syntax Check`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are things that you can try :

1) Save the file (makes sure to add .py extension after file name)

On windows :

i)Search Python in the search bar

ii)Right Click and then click on Open file Location

iii)You will see 3 or more shortcuts in a folder. Right click on anyone of them and then click on Open file location.

iv) Then , copy the location of the directory.

v)Right Click on 'This PC' . Select Properties.

vi) On the right hand side, click on Advanced system settings .

vii) A pop up will appear. From the Advanced tab , click on Environmental Variables.

viii)From System Variables , Click on 'Path' and click 'Edit'.

ix) CLick 'New' and then paste the copied directory there. Click 'OK'

x) Close Sublime and Reopen it.

It should work fine.